# ¿Llamar atributos constantes de una clase desde blade de laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hola tengo la siguiente clase

```
namespace App\Repository\Constants\Models;

class InstanceModelContant
{
    const ALREADY_DEMO = "Usted ya posee un demo.";
    const ALREADY_INSTANCE = "Ya tiene un servidor con estas caracteristicas.";
    const INSTANCE_DEMO_TYPE = "t2.micro";
    const CHAR_NOT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS = "--";
}
```

dentro de la clase se definió varias constantes que uso en varios lugares de todo el proyecto.

en blade me toca hacer una comparacion del atributo de un modelo que quedaria asi

```
@if($instancia->publicip == '--')
                        {{$instancia->publicip}}
                    @else
                    <h1>hola mundo</h1>
                    @endif
```

Pero como ven me toco quemar el codigo el -- 
lo que quiero es usar el atributo **CHAR_NOT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS** dentro de blade y no quemar el código.

O que otra cosa me podrian aconsejar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es tan complicado como te imaginas inclusive puedes mostrar el texto extraido de una de tus constantes y no solo usarlo en tu condición.

```
@if($instancia->publicip == App\Repository\Constants\Models\InstanceModelContant::CHAR_NOT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS)
    {{$instancia->publicip}}
@else
    <h1>hola mundo</h1>
@endif

//Si quisieras reemplazar el hola mundo por un valor extraido de la constante puedes usar
//{{ nombre_de_espacio_de_la_clase_que_contiene_la_constante::NOMBRE_DE_LA_CONSTANTE }}
```

Espero que hayas podido resolver. Saludos